# How to embed the login form of OpenERP in an another website page?

Tags: authentication, odoo

I am working with OpenERP 7, I want to login to OpenERP from another site, I have not to use the standard login page. I want to embed the login form in another site or create a new form and if the user enter valid credentials( DB, login, psswd), he will be redirected to OpenERP web interface.

How can we do that ?

a little bit of help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can point set your OpenERP server ip in your hosting DNS and then make apache server redirect everything that gets to it through port 80 to openERP's port 8069, using apache's [virtualhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html). After this is done just embbed the openerp login page in your website using an [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Regards!